# como encontrar todas las palabras que inicien con vocal en una lista python

Tags: python, caracteres

Necesito mostrar todas las palabras de mas de 8 caracteres que pertenecen a una lista

```
import re

archivo=open("vvhvhv.txt","r",encoding="utf8")
palabra= archivo.read() #texto completo
print(palabra)

patron= r"\b[AaEeIiOoUu]\w+\b"
resultado= re.findall(patron,palabra)

for p in resultado:
    print(p)
```

Comment: ¿Puedes completar la pregunta añadiendo el resultado obtenido y qué esperabas obtener?

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo esta lista de ejemplo:

```py
words = [
    "Airplanes",
    "House",
    "orchestra"
]
```

Dos formas de encontrar aquellas palabras (en **inglés**) en una lista que tengan más de 8 caracteres y empiecen con una vocal son las siguientes:

#### 1. Sin expresiones regulares

```py
# Definimos las vocales en minúscula
vocals = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

# Seleccionamos las palabras
found_words = [w for w in words if len(w) > 8 and w[0].lower() in vocals]
```

`found_words` quedaría así:

```
['Airplanes', 'orchestra']
```

De esta forma, seleccionamos cada valor de `words` que tiene más de 8 caracteres y cuyo primer caracter, en minúscula, se encuentra en `vocals`. Convertimos el primer caracter de cada valor a **minúscula** para poder encontrarlo en `vocals` independientemente de que esté en minúscula o mayúscula.

Para seleccionar palabras en otros **idiomas**, habría que modificar la lista `vocals` en consecuencia. Por ejemplo para el español, habría que añadir vocales con acentos ("á", "é"...).

#### 2. Con una expresión regular

```py
import re

# Definimos la expresión regular
regex = r"[aeiouAEIOU][a-zA-Z]{8,}"

found_words = []

for w in words:
    match = re.match(regex, w)
    
    # Si la palabra encaja con la expresión
    # regular, la incluímos en "found_words".
    if match is not None:
        found_words.append(w)
```

`found_words` quedaría así:

```
['Airplanes', 'orchestra']
```

De esta forma, seleccionamos cada valor de `words` que empiece con una vocal (en mínuscula o mayúscula) y continúe con 8 ó más letras (en minúsculas o mayúsculas).

Para seleccionar palabras en otros **idiomas**, habría que modificar la expresión regular `regex` en consecuencia.

Comment: Se puede omitir "{1}". El patròn calza una vez por default.

Comment: Cierto, gracias por el aviso. Acabo de editar mi respuesta.